# Implement switch into SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sql, listview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

Hello I have set up a simple listview which is populated by a SQL database hence why I'm using a cursor adapter. I have now added a switch to the custom layout but now I need it to simply function by displaying a toast message with its current row position. Could you please have quick look at my code a guide me in the right direction.

Main Activity............

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

   alarmListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.alarmListView);

    databaseHandler = new MyDatabaseHandler(this, null, null, 1);
   displayProductList();

}


private void displayProductList() {
    try
    {
        Cursor cursor = databaseHandler.getAllProducts();
        if (cursor == null)
        {

            return;
        }
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
        {

            return;
        }
        String[] columns = new String[] {

                MyDatabaseHandler.COLUMN_AlARMDATE,
                MyDatabaseHandler.COLUMN_ALARMTIME,
                MyDatabaseHandler.COLUMN_ALARMNAME
        };
        int[] boundTo = new int[] {

                R.id.custom_Date,
                R.id.custom_Time,
                R.id.custom_Name
        };
        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.alarm_list,
                cursor,
                columns,
                boundTo,
                0);
        alarmListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }


}
```

The other two remaining sections are simply my database and getters and setters.

Thank you

Comment: i dont see any `Switch` in your code

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet as I don't know where to put it

Comment: add it to your layout and setup `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` in your `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: But I don't have a separate class from my adapter as it has all been set inside of the mainActivity

Comment: what separate class?

Comment: I'm assuming that when you say SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder you mean to setup another class to hold the adapter?

Comment: check `SimpleCursorAdapter` documentation on how to setup `ViewBinder`

Comment: sure will do....